# Where is the Oracle Bug Database?

Tags: oracle, bug-tracking

They must have hidden the bug database somewhere. I could not find it with Google. Is the bug database public?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [metalink.oracle.com](http://metalink.oracle.com)

Oracle also has public [forums](http://forums.oracle.com).

Comment: This is not public, right? (An oracle support id is needed to access the bug database.)

Comment: @Thomas Jung:  Correct.  Metalink is not public, you must have a support contract.  It lets you search for bugs, get patches, and open support cases.

Comment: When it's up.  And the bug is public.

Comment: "Metalink" resolves to https://support.oracle.com. The stratification/prioritization of requests is managed by something more meaningful in recent years than the name of a precious metal.

Answer (score 22):

No, the Oracle bug database is not public.  It is available to Support customers through [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html) (the website formerly known as Metalink).

If your organisation pays for support you can register on MOS.  You will need to know your CSI number.  Then you'll have to wait while your organisation's account administrator  authorises your registration.

If you don't have a support contract you're out of luck.  Oracle's Support sales comprise pretty much [all of its profit margin](http://www.informationweek.com/news/global-cio/security/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=222002898), which is why they're keen for us to shell out.

Comment: Also, see Trevor Davis' response below, as you can find your own bugs.

Comment: One must question the practice of a corporation who is supported by the customer's inability to use their products. - BTW it is 2014 and the "bug" still remains.

Comment: That profit margin link is dead, unfortunately. Here's an archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20100114024126/http://www.informationweek.com/news/global-cio/security/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=222002898

Answer (score 5):

From Oracle suppport page.

[How_To_Monitor_Outside_In_Bugs_And_Enhancement_Requests_Via_My_Oracle_Support](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html#tab=KBHome%28page=KBHome&id=%28%29%29,%28page=KBNavigator&id=%28from=BOOKMARK&bmDocType=FAQ&viewingMode=1143&bmDocID=841907.1&bmDocDsrc=KB&bmDocTitle=How%20To%20Monitor%20Outside%20In%20Bugs%20And%20Enhancement%20Requests%20Via%20My%20Oracle%20Support%29%29)

Questions and Answers
How Do I Monitor Bugs/Enhancement Requests (ERs) via My Oracle Support?
Progress on your bug/ER can be monitored in My Oracle Support (formerly MetaLink) by following these steps:

1) In the upper right corner there is a "Search Knowledge Base" field
2) To the left of this field is a dropdown menu with alttext “Sources”. Click this dropdown and choose “Bug Number”.
3) Enter the Bug/ER Number in that field and click Find (i.e. the hourglass). 
4) On the Bug/ER that is returned, click on the Star icon to the left to add as a Favorite
5) In the Favorites drop down menu (in the upper right) under the Bugs drop down choice, this Bug/ER is now listed

If using Classic MetaLink these steps can be used:
1) Select Document ID (Knowledge Base, Forum or Bug) in the Quick Find poplist
2) Enter the Bug/ER number in the text field. 
3) Click on Go. 
4) The Bug/ER number and subject appear. 
5) Click on the Bug/ER number in the results window.
6) Click on Bookmark. 
7) Monitor periodically by clicking My Headlines then the Bookmarks button.

Please refer to “Appendix A - Bug/ER status codes and explanations” for the list of status changes you might see with your bugs or ERs.

It can take up to 24 hours for bugs or enhancement requests (ERs) to be visible on My Oracle Support.  If you do not see your bug after 24 hours, please contact Support to inquire.

But again the bug may NOT BE PUBLIC so even if its attached to one of your SR's you still can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realise you could find bugs raised by your account.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle bug database is NOT a public resource--not even for customers with a support contract.  Oracle Support (formally known as Metalink) provides information on bugs that are associated with support tickets opened by contract holders.  These bugs are found in various documents throughout Oracle Support, but there is no public database as exists for Open Source projects like Apache.  Only Oracle employees have access to their internal bug database, and I am certain that the database is proprietary and not something like Bugzilla.

You must have a current support contract with Oracle to access Oracle Support.  However, much information about Oracle technologies can be found in [Oracle Technet](http://otn.oracle.com) (OTN), and there is a discussion forum there where some information from Oracle support has been cross-posted by members.  There are also a large number of web sites dedicated to Oracle products.

Cheers,
Opus

Answer (score 1):

Oracle publish this information in [metalink.oracle.com](http://metalink.oracle.com). But this resource is aviable only to people with support contract